# Cube Drawn in Java using a VBO does not match geometry

Tags: java, opengl, game-engine, lwjgl, vbo

I'm rendering a test cube in java (using the lwjgl) and opengl. The cube itself is a simple 10x10x10 drawn with the following vertex data:

```
float[] vertexData =
    {length/2, length/2, length/2,
    -length/2, length/2, length/2,
    -length/2, length/2, -length/2,
     length/2, length/2, -length/2,
     length/2, -length/2, length/2,
    -length/2, -length/2, length/2,
    -length/2, -length/2, -length/2,
     length/2, -length/2, -length/2};

short[] indexData = {0, 4, 1,
    1, 4, 5,
    1, 5, 2,
    2, 5, 6,
    2, 6, 3,
    3, 7, 6,
    3, 7, 0,
    0, 7, 4,
    3, 0, 2,
    2, 0, 1,
    4, 7, 6,
    5, 4, 6};
```

The variable length is set to 10. (I have omitted my color data for simplicity, but as your about too see it just contains 1,0,0 repeated).

My issue is thus: upon drawing instead of a 10x10x10 I get an approx 4.7x4.7x4.7. I have run sevral tests (ie: drawing geometry using glBegin as well as placing two cubes with there centers 10 pixels appart too see if they touched they did not)

I have packaged VBO in a class of my own creation, the contents of which is below:

```
 public class BasicVBO {

 IntBuffer ib = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(3);

 int vHandle = ib.get(0);
 int cHandle = ib.get(1);
 int iHandle = ib.get(2);

 float[] vertexData;
 float[] colorData;
 short[] indexData;


public BasicVBO(float[] vertexArray, float[] textArray, short[] indexArray){

 vertexData = vertexArray;
 colorData = textArray;
 indexData = indexArray; 


FloatBuffer vBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(vertexArray.length);
FloatBuffer cBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(colorData.length);
ShortBuffer iBuffer = BufferUtils.createShortBuffer(indexArray.length);

glGenBuffers(ib);
  vHandle = ib.get(0);
  cHandle = ib.get(1);
  iHandle = ib.get(2);



    vBuffer.put(vertexData);
    vBuffer.flip();


    cBuffer.put(colorData);
    cBuffer.flip();


    iBuffer.put(indexData);
    iBuffer.flip();

  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iHandle);
  glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, iBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vHandle);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);


  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cHandle);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, cBuffer, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW_ARB);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);



}



public void Draw(float x,float y,float z,float a,float b,float c,float d){

   glPushMatrix();

    glTranslatef(x, y, z);
    glRotatef((float)(Math.toDegrees(a)),b,c,d);


  glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vHandle);
  glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,  3 << 2 , 0L);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cHandle);
  glColorPointer(3, GL_FLOAT,  3 << 2  , 0L);
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iHandle);

  glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES,indexData.length  , GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0L);

  glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

  glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
  glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);

   glPopMatrix(); 

}



}
```

And it is used in the following manner in my games while loop:

```
       //////////
       //render//
       //////////

       switch (gamemode) {
           case Intro:

               break;
           case MainMenu:
               switch (menupage) {

               }
               break;
           case Game:
               switch (submode) {
                   case fp:
                       //setting fp settings



                       // camera for fp
                       MyCamera.ConvertToVectorAndDraw(cameraPosition); **//unrelated camera function**





                       //drawing for fp//

                //3d here

   glPushMatrix();


                     World.Render(); **//This is the draw function for the VBO**

                     //Draw plans to check sizing

                     glBegin(GL_QUADS);
                     glColor3f(0,1,0);
                     glVertex3f(5,-5,(float)(9.5));
                     glVertex3f(-5,-5,(float)(9.5));
                     glVertex3f(-5,5,(float)(9.5));
                     glVertex3f(5,5,(float)(9.5));
                     glEnd();



                    **//The above draws a 10x10 square at the correct scale**





    glPopMatrix();




   //  Set Up for 2D 

                       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                       glPushMatrix();
                       glLoadIdentity();
                       glOrtho(0.0, Display.getWidth(), Display.getHeight(), 0.0, -1.0, 10.0);
                       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
                       glLoadIdentity();
                       glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

                       glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);



                //2D here




      //  Reprep for 3D 

                       glPopMatrix();
                       glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
                       glPopMatrix();
                       glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);





               }
               break;
       }
```

In short, I pass my vertex and index data as above into the initialize function of my vbo class, then use its draw function in my render loop. The image draws, just not at the require vertex positions (as prev. said, it draws a 4.7x4.7x4.7 cube aspect ration intact).

I have been playing with various function in both my render section and the vbo class and cannot make the object draw correctly as of yet.

UPDATE:

Sorry this had taken so long to answer but I forgot I posted the question. The issue was glRotate. The data I was passing to it was unrotated but also had 0,0,0 as the vector about which to rotate. This gives an undefined result and in my cause resized the object.
So there you go, my math rather than my coding was off.

Comment: What are you using to measure your cube dimensions, where are you getting the 4.7 number from?

Comment: Matching them using logic. I placed two cubes close enough together so they just touched. The green square draw function below my World.render function also draws a square that is 10x10 and the cube does not line up with it.

Comment: Your green squares z = 9.5, when your cubes z = 0 without translation. Are you translating it's origin to z = 9.5? Are you using perspective projection for your 3D rendering? For a sanity check use an ortho projection for both, and I bet they both appear the same size.

Comment: @Pondwater I have adjusted both back to the origin. I'm using modelview and ortho now

Comment: The issue remains, even if I convert to an ortho projection

Comment: I tested the  projection matrices ad nauseam as initially I suspected the as the culprit. However, both the square and the cube are drawn under the same matrix conditions they cannot be the culprit. Nor does it account for the other size tests I did.

Comment: Either there is some form of transform pipeline leak or the buffer does not contains the correct values. Try reading the values from the VBO using glMapBufferRange to ensure they are correct.